# Getting error saying "cannot read property of pipe undefined" I am trying to filter my data after getting all data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, collections, google-cloud-firestore

Below is my function i am using to filter the data. Error is saying pipe property undefined .

```
   filterMat(){ 
     this.material = this.userservice.matmodel$.pipe(
       switchMap(user =>
        this.auth.collection$(`users/${this.userservice.getUID()}/MatModel`, ref =>
        ref
        .where('uid','==',user.uid)
       // .where(this.Zita,'==',user.Zita)
        .orderBy('date','desc')
        )
       )
     )

   }
```

This is my collection$

```
collection$(path, query?) {
        return this.afs
          .collection(path, query)
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions => {
              return actions.map(a => {
                const data: Object = a.payload.doc.data();
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              });
            })
          );
      }
```

my matmodel$ is

```
matmodel$:Observable<MatModel>
```

Comment: Looks like `this.userservice.matmodel$` is `undefined`. Please show the UserService code.

Comment: this is my matmodel$                                                                 matmodel$:Observable<MatModel>

Comment: @zimgamer We need to assign value to matmodel$

const con = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

    con.pipe(
      filter((value) => value % 2 === 0)
    ).subscribe(value => console.log(value));

Here output is '2, 4, 6, 8'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `matmodel$` is declared but not yet defined.

Try replacing

```js
matmodel$: Observable<MatModel>;
```

with

```js
matmodel$ = new Observable<MatModel>();
```

Comment: its showing this in the console.log                                                                                            Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: SwitchMapOperator}
_isScalar: false
source: Observable {_isScalar: false}
operator: SwitchMapOperator {project: ƒ}
__proto__: Object

Comment: @zimgamer: Could you please elaborate? Do you print the log or is it an error? If you are printing the log could you please update what you print in the question?

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you. Was printing the log.